# ¿Cómo solucionar este error al crear una base de datos en postgresql?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

el código errado es:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'BDBanco_Estudiante'
 WITH
 OWNER = postgres
 ENCODING = 'UTF8'
 CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
 IS_TEMPLATE = False;
```

el error fue:

```
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «'BDBanco_Estudiante'»
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE 'BDBanco_Estudiante'
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lleva comilla simple en el nombre de la base de datos que se quiere crear.

```
CREATE DATABASE BDBanco_Estudiante
 WITH
 OWNER = postgres
 ENCODING = 'UTF8'
 CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
 IS_TEMPLATE = False;
```